# Can't acess ajax post request in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I've searched everywhere but can't find an answer to this problem.

I'm writing a little ajax script but can't get the correct value of the POST request.
This is the code so far:

```
 <textarea id="message" name="message" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
 <input value="SEND" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;" type = 'button' onclick = 'ajaxFunction()'/>



<script type="text/javascript">                             <!--
            //Browser Support Code
            function ajaxFunction(){
               var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

               try {
                  // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                  ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
               }catch (e) {
                  // Internet Explorer Browsers
                  try {
                     ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                  }catch (e) {
                     try{
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                     }catch (e){
                        // Something went wrong
                        alert("Your browser broke!");
                        return false;
                     }
                  }
               }

               // Create a function that will receive data 
               // sent from the server and will update
               // div section in the same page.

               ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                     var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('chbox');
                     ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                  }
               }

               // Now get the value from user and pass it to
               // server script.

               var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
               var queryString = message ;
               ajaxRequest.open("POST", 'chatdata.php', true);
               //ajaxRequest.send(null); 
               ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
               ajaxRequest.send('queryString');
            }
</script>



<?php
$message1 = $_REQUEST['message'];
echo $message;
?>
```

when i use `print_r($message);` to see the content of the POST value
this is what i get Array ( [queryString] => ). It has no values.
What could be wrong with my code? 
(I would have used jQuery but i'm not well grounded in it yet.)

Comment: You need to set the parameter name.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9713078).

Comment: Maybe `var queryString = "queryString=" + message;`? Remember that post data is a series of `key=value` pairs like this: `key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&...`

Comment: It would be beneficial to define an event handler that uses the XMLHttpRequest object, rather than define an event handler that directly instantiates an XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed some bugs and code start works:

1.

```
<p id="chbox"></p> <!-- ajaxDisplay need this -->
```

2.

```
ajaxRequest.send("message="+queryString); //queryString is variable so without quotes
```

3.

```
var_dump($message1); //there was message without 1
```

Comment: It's good now. Before you've written `ajaxRequest.send('queryString')` instead of what you write now. Javascript interpreted 'queryString' as string instead of a variable. Now you put `ajaxRequest.send("message="+queryString);` , queryString is a variable instead of string here

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would do it in jQuery - much simpler:

```js
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
 var txt = $('#message').val();
 $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
   url: 'my_ajax_processor_file.php',
  data: 'ta=' + txt,
  success: function(d){
   if (d.length) alert(d);
  }
 });

}); //END mybutt.click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="message" name="message" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
<input id="mybutt" value="SEND" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;" type='button' />
```

**my_ajax_processor_file.php**

```
<?php
    $txt = $_POST['ta'];
    $out = 'You sent: ' .$txt;
    echo $out;
```

---

[Here are a bunch of free 5-min video tuts for jQuery](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=32)

Comment: Always someone running to JQuery.

Comment: August 26, 2006 is Internet's third birthday, second was on January same year (Firebug).

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge I guess you didn't read the question. OP commented he would prefer to do this in jQuery but didn't know how. Nice to read your kind comment, though.

Comment: @gibberish Sorry, it does not say that either. "I would have used jQuery..."

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is with query string. You should put `ajaxRequest.send(queryString)` instead of `ajaxRequest.send('queryString');`. Don't use query string just use the name of the variable. It should work!

Comment: He has no such variable at all.

Comment: Yes there is on in `var queryString = message ;` in the code

Comment: Indeed, sorry haven't seen it at all.

Comment: Not mine, sorry again. (but i'll vote it up, if it would make you happy :) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112967/discussion-between-pierre-robentz-cassion-and-skobaljic).